# jQuery.show() not working in IE 8, Safari 5.1

Tags: jquery, html

I've got the following code (which you can see in play at http://jsfiddle.net/5dbZx/). I am running jQuery version v1.6.1. For some reason, **.show() (and I've also tried .toggle()) will not work on this in IE 8 or Safari 5.1** - I've tried both in Win XP and 7. It DOES work on FireFox 3.6 and IE 9.

I've done some searching, and it appears that .show does in fact work on IE 8, and that something else must be causing the error in this code. But I'm not sure what. Thanks!

```
<table>
    <tr class="form_row">
        <td class="required_label" id="Example1">
              Example 1:
         </td>
         <td class="input_field">
             <select name="course_type" id="course_type">
                 <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                 <option value="1" onclick="$('#Example2').show();" >choice 1</option>
                 <option value="2" onclick="$('#Example2').show();" >choice 2</option>
                 <option value="3" onclick="$('#Example2').show();" >choice 3</option>
                 <option value="4" onclick="$('#Example2').hide();" >choice 4</option>
             </select>
         </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="form_row" id="Example2" style="display: none;">
        <td class="required_label">
            Example 2:
        </td>
        <td class="input_field">
            <select name="select_statement" id="select_statement">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OnClick doesn't work in an option on ie8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845848/ie8-simple-alert-is-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cant place onclick events on select options, it will not trigger in all browsers. Try using the `onchange` event of the `select` instead.

```
$("#course_type").change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 4) {
    $("#Example2").hide();
  }
  else {
    $("#Example2").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer treats select boxes slightly different than the rest of the document.
IE doesn't notice events in childnodes of select elements, only the select elements themselves.

I normally setup my functions to work depending on either of the selects value or selectedIndex attribute & using the onchange event.

Answer (score 1):

See the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // use of .on() requires jQuery 1.7+
    // for previous versions use the following instead:
    // $("#courseType").change(function() {
    $("#courseType").on("change", function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val === "4") {
            $("#Example2").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#Example2").show();
        }
    });
});
```

This will require updates to your HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="form_row">
        <td class="required_label" id="Example1">
              Example 1:
         </td>
         <td class="input_field">
             <select name="course_type" id="course_type">
                 <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                 <option value="1">choice 1</option>
                 <option value="2">choice 2</option>
                 <option value="3">choice 3</option>
                 <option value="4">choice 4</option>
             </select>
         </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="form_row" id="Example2" style="display: none;">
        <td class="required_label">
            Example 2:
        </td>
        <td class="input_field">
            <select name="select_statement" id="select_statement">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="0">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smendola/5dbZx/1/

The HTML is changed as follows:

```
<option value="1" data-show="show" >choice 1</option>
<option value="2" data-show="show" >choice 2</option>
<option value="3" data-show="show" >choice 3</option>
<option value="4" data-show="hide" >choice 4</option>
```

and the JS is:

```
$('#course_type').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-show') == "show") {
        $('#Example2').show();
    } else {
        $('#Example2').hide();
    }
});
```

[EDIT]
Bit simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/smendola/5dbZx/2/

```
<option value="3" data-show="1" >choice 3</option>
<option value="4" data-show="0" >choice 4</option>
```

JS:

```
$('#course_type').change(function() {
    var show = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-show');
    $('#Example2').toggle(show);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here also is not working, chrome 11 .. 
Try do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
              $('#course_type').click(function(){
                     $('#Example2').show();
              });
       });
</script>
<table>
       <tr class="form_row">
              <td class="required_label" id="Example1">
                     Example 1:
              </td>
              <td class="input_field">
                     <select name="course_type" id="course_type">
                            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option value="1">choice 1</option>
                            <option value="2">choice 2</option>
                            <option value="3">choice 3</option>
                            <option value="4">choice 4</option>
                     </select>

              </td>
       </tr>    
       <tr class="form_row" id="Example2" style="display: none;">
              <td class="required_label">
                     Example 2:
              </td>
              <td class="input_field">
                     <select name="select_statement" id="select_statement">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                            <option value="0">No</option>
                     </select>
              </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```